# Tor hidden services doesn't seem to be working for me

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

I cannot seem to access any onion site while on Tor.  It was working fine about a week maybe a week and a half ago, then all of the sudden it just stopped connecting to any onion site at all.  I have absolutely no idea what happened.  I am not very  good with computers so I am very curious and nervous about what happened  (whether I did something wrong) and what I can do to fix it.

I would really appreciate some help with this matter.  Also if please be patient with me if I ask stupid questions on how to fix it.  I am afraid that I am not very tech savvy.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you access this hidden service: http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion/ It is the homepage of the Tor project.

Comment: No, when I click the link I the message that says server not found.

Comment: Alright. Since that link works for the rest of us, let's take a step back. I will assume you are using TBB (Tor Browser Bundle) on a computer. First, try to completely remove your TBB installation, deleting its folder. Then install it again in a new folder. Does it work now? It not, can you visit this page to verify Tor is working at all: https://check.torproject.org/

Comment: Yes I am and sadly no it doesn't work when I reinstalled TBB.  When I checked the website you posted it said that I was not connected.  I tried some of the suggestions like setting the clock, and that seems fine.  I run Norton, but it has never caused a problem before.  I am sadly becoming very frustrated and have no idea on what is going on.

I hope that I am not being a bother, I just cannot figure out why it just stopped working all of the sudden and it is driving me up the wall.

Comment: If that page linked said "Sorry. You are not using Tor.", and you tried several times, and also have restarted your computer in between, it is now safe to assume Tor is in fact not being used at all. Next thing to do is figure out why, and fix it! In Tor Browser, open the properties dialog (I am not using Windows, so cannot tell where it is for you). Select the tab "Advanced", then select the sub-tab "Network", and click on "Settings...". Is "Manual proxy configuration" selected? What does HTTP-proxy and SOCKS-host say? What does "No proxy for:" say?

Comment: Here is what is it says.  What is selected at the moment is "Use the recommend proxy settings for my version of Firefox"  
The HTTP has nothing written and SOCKS says 127.0.0.1 and the Port 9150.  No proxies has 127.0.0.1

Comment: I don't know if it matters but my IP address is different on the check torproject website then what it says when I check it the tor bundle. I don't why it would be different but maybe that is a clue to why its not working

Comment: Sorry to keep posting but is there anyone that can help with with my problem.  I am really getting frustrated that I cannot activate and use tor.  I still have no idea what is wrong, and need some help desperately.

Comment: Check your computer clock and timezone settings.

Comment: Did you update Windows to Windows 10? Tor and Window 10 was not working for me for some reason; had to downgrade back down to Windows 7.