# Tor will not allow me to view . onion sites

Tags: browsers

I downloaded Tor a few days ago and It will not allow me to see any .onion sites. All other sites seem to be working but when I try hidden services I get Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at XXXXXXXXXX. I have tried many options. I have even turned off my firewall. Nothing Happened.

Comment: Are you using TBB or regular Firefox? If you are using regular Firefox try switching to the Tor browser bundle. It could also be that due to the short life/periodic up time of most hidden sevices they were simply unreachable. I personally have found approx 90% percent of hidden services to be down.

Comment: The hidden services you are trying to access may be down. Try the Duck Duck Go hidden service at http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/ or the example hidden service at http://duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion/ (both of which are fairly reliable) and see if they work.

Comment: Related question: [Tor hidden services doesn't seem to be working for me](http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1372/114)

Comment: Same problem on android 4.4.2.. I know the services are not down because I can accesses them in my PC (windows) and my phone (android 5).